# How do I flow-annotate a clone function?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to add Flow annotations to a simple clone function, and it doesn't look possible currently. Here's an attempt:

```
// @flow
var clone = function<T>(obj: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(clone);
    }
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        var value = {};
        for (var i in obj) {
            value[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return value;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I'm using generic type T to indicate that return type will be the same as the input type. However, Flow returns the following error:

```
11:         return value;
                   ^^^^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
2: var clone = function<T>(obj: T): T {
               ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`
```

On the object code branch, Flow knows that returned type T will be an object — why can't it be compatible with an object literal then? And if it can't, how do I annotate this properly?

I can add `(value: any)` in this branch, but Flow coverage won't be full in this case (complaining about `any`).

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but in my opinion it's not worth spending a lot of time trying to properly typecheck functions like this. The beauty of gradual type systems is that you can pick and choose where to apply them. Small functions like this can easily be understood by humans and are easy to test. In my opinion, typecheckers shine when applied to large systems that a human can't easily understand in their entirety. As long as you have the interface annotated properly (which you do), write a few tests and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you have to prove to Flow that `value` indeed has type `T`.

First of all, your implementation obviously doesn't work for every possible `T`. What about prototypes? What about non-enumerable properties? What about builtins, like `Date`, `RegExp`, etc?

To be fair, even you will implement cloning in every possible detail, Flow won't be able to see it, it's just too complicated.

When you want to exploit Javascript's dynamism is such a way, you will most likely have to abandon type-safety for implementation.